# Jest Change Mock Object's Function's Value

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to have a different response from the same function of an object with jest mocks. In first test case I will assert cache hit and second case I want to see cache miss.

## Cache Data Access

```
module.exports = class CacheDataAccess {
  constructor({ config, Redis }) {
    this.config = config;
    this.redisClient = Redis;
  }

  async getCached({ cacheKey }) {
    const { redisClient } = this;

    return redisClient.getAsync(this.getKeyWithNamespace(cacheKey));
  }
};
```

## Cache Service

```
async getCached({ cacheKey }) {
    const { logger, CacheDataAccess } = this;
    const cached = await CacheDataAccess.getCached({ cacheKey });

    if (cached) {
      return cached;
    }
    else{
      return {};
    }
}
```

Here is my mock

## Cache Service Test

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // Clear all instances and calls to constructor and all methods:
    CacheDataAccess.mockClear();
    cacheService = new CacheService({
      logger,
      CacheDataAccess: new CacheDataAccess(),
    });
  });

const CacheDataAccess = require('../../../src/data-access/cache');

jest.mock('../../../src/data-access/cache'); // CacheDataAccess is now a mock constructor

CacheDataAccess.mockImplementation(() => ({
  isEnabled: jest.fn(() => (true)),
  getCached: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(cachedObject).mockReturnValueOnce(false),
}));

  it('should get cached object on cache hit', async () => {
    const response = await cacheService.getCached({ cacheKey: cachedObject });
    expect(response).toEqual({ cached: JSON.parse(cachedObject) });
  });

  it('should return empty object on cache miss', async () => {
    //I NEED EMPTY RESPONSE HERE BECAUSE OF CACHE MISS
    const response = await cacheService.getCached({ cacheKey: 'test' });
    expect(response).toEqual({});
  });
```

How can I get empty response in second test case?

Comment: Nope it doesnt work

Comment: You can try to use `jest.clearAllMocks()` in the before each and mock inside each test.
`cacheService.getCached.mockReturnValueOnce({})` (you needed an empty object, no?)